# Load National Elevation Data into a WMS server?

Tags: wms, elevation

We have an application that can pull WMS data from the National Elevation Data set (NED) and use it to perform a number of run-time calculations.  We have been pulling it from NASA JPL WMS servers here (http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/) but we are pulling too much data for their servers to support.  We tried using the WMS tiling extension they support, but since it is non-standard (ie. it is not TMS) we can't find any proxy or caching tools that support it (eg. TileCache, MapProxy, etc).

Does anyone know of a WMS cache that does support the NASA JPL servers?  If not, can anyone give me some guidance on where to get the raw data and how to host it up ourselves locally?  (a tutorial link would be very helpful as we don't host any other WMS data locally and would basically be starting from scratch).

Answer (score 3):

You can download NED from [this site](http://cumulus.cr.usgs.gov/webappcontent/neddownloadtool/NEDDownloadToolDMS.html). For serving them, depending on your back-end technology of choice, [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/homepage.action) is your friend. Or you can go the ArcGIS Server way.
If you want to do calculation on the pixel values on the client side, I would advise using a WCS service instead of a WMS which is merely for display.

Comment: Is there anywhere to download the entire US dataset?  Or is there a better dataset to use?